# Viewing transaction events by using web3 on geth console

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, events, console, receipts

According to https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractEvents.myEvent

web3 allows to extract the pertinent logs from a transaction receipt:

```
tx_hash = contract.functions.myFunction(12345).transact({'to':contract_address})
tx_receipt = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
rich_logs = contract.events.myEvent().processReceipt(tx_receipt)
rich_logs[0]['args']
    {'myArg': 12345}
```

but when using this code on geth console I got this error:

```
receipt = web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x38b269e2fd7d8a2d8c814749ee252d98eaabe908203315c587e46f44a8b172d4")
erc20.events.Transfer().processReceipt(receipt)
    TypeError: Cannot access member 'Transfer' of undefined
```

being "Transfer" the event to query and erc20 a valid deployed contract

The value for erc20.events is

```
undefined
```

nevertheless erc20 seems ok:

```
erc20
{
  abi: [{
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "name",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "approve",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "totalSupply",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
      name: "transferFrom",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "decimals",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "initialSupply",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "mint",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "standard",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [],
      name: "halt",
      outputs: [],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "balanceOf",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}],
      name: "updateOwner",
      outputs: [],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "operations",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "contractBalance",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "owner",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "transferOrigin",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "symbol",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "destroy",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "transfer",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [],
      name: "halted",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: false,
      inputs: [],
      name: "unhalt",
      outputs: [],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      constant: true,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "allowance",
      outputs: [{...}],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "view",
      type: "function"
  }, {
      inputs: [],
      payable: false,
      stateMutability: "nonpayable",
      type: "constructor"
  }, {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
      name: "Transfer",
      type: "event"
  }, {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
      name: "Approval",
      type: "event"
  }, {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "Mint",
      type: "event"
  }, {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}],
      name: "Destroy",
      type: "event"
  }, {
      anonymous: false,
      inputs: [{...}, {...}, {...}],
      name: "Halt",
      type: "event"
  }],
  address: "0x88e726de6cbadc47159c6ccd4f7868ae7a037730",
  transactionHash: null,
  Approval: function(),
  Destroy: function(),
  Halt: function(),
  Mint: function(),
  Transfer: function(),
  allEvents: function(),
  allowance: function(),
  approve: function(),
  balanceOf: function(),
  contractBalance: function(),
  decimals: function(),
  destroy: function(),
  halt: function(),
  halted: function(),
  initialSupply: function(),
  mint: function(),
  name: function(),
  operations: function(),
  owner: function(),
  standard: function(),
  symbol: function(),
  totalSupply: function(),
  transfer: function(),
  transferFrom: function(),
  transferOrigin: function(),
  unhalt: function(),
  updateOwner: function()
```

How can I view transaction events for a given contract and txhash by using web3 on geth console? Thx!

Comment: Geth's console uses web3 v0.20 so you might to try the old syntax https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events, but I'm not sure that version supports processing receipts.

Comment: I've used this trick with v0.20 `var allEvents = w3.myContract.allEvents(); var eventLog = allEvents.formatter(logEntry);`. I'd check when I've time if that trick does work from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer is an event of ERC-20 token having declaration as:

```
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
```

You need to fire Transfer event by passing these three parameteres also.

Comment: Transfer event is fired because the transaction calls contract method transfer. I just need to get the event data recorded on the transaction to verify everything is working ok